# merge rows with conditional in if statement

Tags: r, merge, conditional-statements, rows

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
df <- data.frame ("ID"=c(a, b, c, c, d, e, e), "K"= c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                       "P"=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1), "C"=c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1))
  ID K P C
   a 1 1 1
   b 1 1 2
   c 1 1 1
   c 1 1 2
   d 1 2 1
   e 1 2 2
   e 1 1 1
```

I'm trying to collapse rows with the same ID value.

For rows that have no duplicated ID value I want that row to remain untouched.

For rows with a duplicated ID value (c & e) I want it to collapse the rows. For each of the columns (K, P, C) I want it to look at the values of each of the duplicated rows. If both values in the K column = 1 then the output should remain a 1. If both the values in the K column don't equal 1, then the output should be a -99. Same for column P and column C.

So ideally the output would look like:

```
  ID K  P   C
1  a 1  1   1
2  b 1  1   2
3  c 1  1  -99
5  d 1  2   1
6  e 1 -99 -99
```

So far I've only gotten to :

```
for (row in 1:nrow(df) ) {
  if length(df$ID) >=2



 }
```

But I'm pretty stuck because I don't even know if this is the correct way to begin.

Thanks!

Comment: It's nor very clear (at least for me) the criteria, could you please explain it with more details??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plyr` package is useful here.

### Original version

```
df <- data.frame ("ID"=c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5), "K"= c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                  "P"=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1), "C"=c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1))
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .variables = .(ID),
      summarize,
      K = if (length(K) == 1) K else if (all(K == 1)) 1 else -99,
      P = if (length(P) == 1) P else if (all(P == 1)) 1 else -99,
      C = if (length(C) == 1) C else if (all(C == 1)) 1 else -99)
```

### Version that preserves additional columns

Note that this code assumes that your additional columns have identical values for all rows with the same ID.

```
df <- data.frame ("ID"=c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5), "K"= c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                  "P"=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1), "C"=c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1),
                  "extra1" = c("a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e", "e"),
                  "extra2" = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E", "E"))
library(plyr)
df1 <- ddply(df, .variables = .(ID),
             summarize,
             K = if (length(K) == 1) K else if (all(K == 1)) 1 else -99,
             P = if (length(P) == 1) P else if (all(P == 1)) 1 else -99,
             C = if (length(C) == 1) C else if (all(C == 1)) 1 else -99)
df2 <- merge(df1, unique(df[, setdiff(names(df), c("K", "P", "C"))]),
             by = "ID")
```

Comment: this worked great! thanks so much! Just a quick question. Is there a good tool for learning the plyr package? It seems to be pretty useful.

Comment: actually another question, it seems when I run this in my data it doesn't keep other untouched columns. In my data I have like 6 other columns that have additional information for each row but I don't know how to keep those columns?

Comment: Don't know of any plyr materials, sorry! There are lots on Google though, e.g. http://seananderson.ca/courses/12-plyr/plyr_2012.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

here's a different approach using baseR:

```
df <- data.frame ("ID"=c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5), "K"= c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                  "P"=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1), "C"=c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1))

dupl = with(df, duplicated(ID, K, P))
df$c = with(df, ifelse(dupl == TRUE & K == 1, -99, C)
```